# Enumerate problem with "list index out of range"

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have a chunk of code that basically goes like this:

```
x = [6237,5342,9991,6237,1021]
y = [0,0,0,0,0]
for i in x:
  index = x.index(i)
  actualindex = [i for i, n in enumerate(x) if n == i][y[index]]
```

apparently there is an error on the fifth line where "list index out of range" the first time that `i = 6237`.

I changed `n == i` into `n == 6237` and everything worked, but when I changed it back to `n == i` it stopped working again and returned the same error as before.

Comment: `for i in range x:` is a syntax error. Please read [mre] and make sure (by **trying it yourself**) that you show code, that someone else can **copy and paste, without changing anything** and see the **exact** error. Please also read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you understand how to post multi-line code with correct formatting. Instead of telling us about the error, **show** a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message that corresponds to the example, formatted like code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an element from an empty list.

This code:

```
x = [6237,5342,9991,6237,1021]
my_list = [i for i, n in enumerate(x) if n == i]
```

always returns an empty list, since the number of elements in x is only 5 **i** can only ever be equal to {0,1,2,3,4} therefore **i** can never equal any of the elements in x since all of them are greater than 4.

```
print(len(my_list)) # 0
my_list[0]
```

gives "list index out of range" because any index you give to the list will be out of range since its length is zero (its an empty list).